# Not enough space to show ad! when running within a TabActivity

Tags: android, admob

I'm trying to use the newly released Google admob SDK (GoogleAdMobAdsSdkAndroid-4.0.4).

The following:

```
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.my_layout);
        AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER,"my_publisher_id");
        layout.addView(adView);
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
        request.setTesting(true);
        adView.loadAd(request);
```

is working just fine in an Activity. However, when I include the above
Activity within a TabActivity, AdView stops working and says:

WARN/Ads(17559): Not enough space to show ad! Wants: <480, 75>, Has: <448, 495>

Any idea how can I include AdView within a TabActivity? Not
necessarily within each Activity, I'd be happy with the AdView just on
top of the Tabs, but that is not working neither.

Many TIA

Comment: Seems that `TabActivity` realize that ad is evil :)

Comment: Ads are not evil.  The user gets something for nothing on most ad supported apps.  I make a whopping $0.10/day on ad revenue.  Hardly enough for my time, but I enjoy what I do.  If my app were $1.60 I'd make $1.00 per installation and assuming a drastic drop in downloads to 1% of current volume that'd be 20 installs.  Far and away more than I've made on ads ($4.45), but in the end there are 800 active users that have to view an ad to use my app for free ... seems like a fair trade.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem was in the padding on the LinearLyout that is within the Tabhost. Removed padding and problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the default padding from the main activity

```
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
```

Remove this padding and it is solved :)